# Best way to create 'optional' models in a Django reusable app

Tags: python, django, inheritance, code-reuse

I'm trying to create a reusable app where I define some abstract models, and some concrete versions of those models that the user can use if they don't want to inherit the models themselves. If the user *does* want to create their own subclasses then I don't want Django to create these concrete models.

This is the solution I have at the moment:

myapp/abstract.py

```
class AbstractModel1:
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class AbstractModel2:
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    field2 = models.ForeignKey(getattr(settings, 'ABSTRACTMODEL1_OVERRIDE', 'myapp.ConcreteModel1'))
```

myapp/models.py

```
if not hasattr(settings, 'ABSTRACTMODEL1_OVERRIDE'):
    class ConcreteModel1(AbstractModel1):
        pass

if not hasattr(settings, 'ABSTRACTMODEL2_OVERRIDE'):
    class ConcreteModel2(AbstractModel2):
        pass
```

Then in the user's app, they can either use the concrete models as provided, or if not then they can create their own subclasses of the model like so:

userapp/models.py

```
class CustomModel1(AbstractModel1):
    extrafield1 = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

userapp/settings.py

```
ABSTRACTMODEL1_OVERRIDE = "userapp.CustomModel1"
```

Is this the best way to achieve this? Am I setting myself up for difficulties when trying to migrate changes in the subclassed models? What if the user wants to use the provided concrete classes first then migrate to a custom class?

Comment: The Django auth.User model is an implementation of swappable models, which sounds like exactly what you want, but the API was never made official. Looks like https://github.com/wq/django-swappable-models/blob/master/README.md is an attempt at doing that.

Comment: Thanks, I had a look through that and `django-swappable-models` installs the concrete models (that have been swapped out) as well as the subclasses, and I'm not sure why this is done.